# In SQLAlchemy, how do I return a ResultProxy instead of a list?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a very simple query in SQLAlchemy that is working fine, something like:

```
query = session.query(MyModel)
query = query.filter(MyModel.col1 == 'foo')
# .. additional filters here...
result = query.limit(50).all()
```

This returns a result that is type `list` -- how can I return a `ResultProxy` object instead WITHOUT using `session.execute()`?  I am using the `query()` method in order to construct a dynamic query with optional filter parameters, but the `ResultProxy` object has some attributes that I would like to use (e.g. `rowcount`).

One of the most confusing things with SQLAlchemy is perhaps the difference between the query methods and its `execute` methods.  Can someone help clear this up with an example?

Comment: Why can't you use `len(result)`?

Comment: I want the number of rows BEFORE the limit, similar ato what `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` or `SELECT FOUND_ROWS();`would offer in MySQL, but in a database agnostic way... but this brings up another question because `result_proxy.rowcount` doesn't seem to know about the size of the result set prior to limiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, this was simpler than I thought: simply use `session.execute(query)`:

```
query = query.limit(50).offset(0)
result_proxy = session.execute(query)
print(result_proxy.rowcount)
```

Comment: Done - one has to wait 2 days before one can accept their own answer.